# Dystopian books where society is split into 3 classes: lower, middle and untouchables, teenagers are trained to be killers

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

I’m trying to identify a book by a rather vague plot line that I’ve been given...
Society is split into three classes. The lower, middle and untouchables. Teenagers are trained to be SAS type killers.

Comment: This is extremely brief and at least borderline too broad because of a lack of details. Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can remember (or whoever gave you the vague details can remember) that you could [edit] in?

Comment: What do you mean by "you've been given"? Did someone give you this description? Can you ask them for more details? For instance, are they sure that it's three and not five divisions, for instance?

Comment: My friend has listened to the audio books on YouTube a few years ago and now wants to read the books but can’t recall much else about the books. It may have been 5 divisions but he specified three.

Answer (score 4):

Could be **[Uglies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uglies) by Scott Westerfeld**. The book and its sequels "Pretties" and "Specials" takes place in a dystopian future where children are born as "Uglies". The three factions your friend might be thinking of correspond to each of the titles in the series.

From the wikipedia article (which sums up the societal factions):

> Everyone on their sixteenth birthday receives the “pretty” operation which transforms them into the society's standard of beautiful. After the operation, new Pretties cross the river that divides the city and lead a new life with no responsibilities or obligations. There are two other operations available, one to transform Pretties into “Middle-Pretties” (adults with a job), and another to transform Middle-Pretties into "Crumblies".

Without giving too much away, the "Pretty" procedure turns them into model citizens in every way. Inevitably, there are some dissenters who do not undergo the standard procedures, they're known as "Smokies", and on top of that, there are special operatives: the "Specials". The Specials act as a sort of law enforcement agency to make sure everyone gets their proper procedures. They have enhanced physicality/senses (from the "Special" procedure) and could be viewed as "SAS type killers".

A quick search shows that you can find the Audiobooks on YouTube.